# Intergal Calculation

Tags: calculus, integration

Can someone suggest me how to solve this integal
$$
I = \int_0^\infty  {\frac{{\sqrt {ax + b} }}{x}} {e^{ - \mu x}}dx
$$
with $a,b,\mu$ are postive real numbers.

Comment: Actually I think that integral can be represented by special functions like exponential integral or Gamma function. However, I haven't find out yet. So I need help from someones who might know it.

Comment: @widapol Nothing fancy like Gamma function is required here. Your integral diverges by simple comparison with $1/x$.

Comment: @julien Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your integrand is positive and, as $x$ approaches $0$, we have:
$$
\frac{\sqrt{ax+b}}{x}e^{-\mu x} \sim \frac{\sqrt{b}}{x}.
$$

So the integral diverges at $0$.

Note: it seems to me that equivalents are not very popular over here, so if you prefer, you can use comparison by using that $e^t\geq 1+t$ for all $t$:
$$
\frac{\sqrt{ax+b}}{x}e^{-\mu x} \geq \frac{\sqrt{b}}{x}(1-\mu x)=\frac{\sqrt{b}}{x}-\mu\sqrt{b}.
$$
Now again, the integral of the RHS diverges at $0$, so your integral diverges.

Comment: What if a and b are not positive? They are just real numbers.

Comment: Your question said that they were positive. For $\sqrt{ax+b}$ to be defined on $(0,+\infty)$, you must have $b\geq 0$ and $a\geq 0$. Now if $a=0$ and $b=0$, the function is $0$ so the integral is $0$. If $a=0$ and $b>0$, the same argument as above works, and the integral diverges. Finally, if $b=0$ and $a>0$, now the integral converges since the integrand is equivalent to $\sqrt{b}/\sqrt{x}$ at $0$ (it always converges at $+\infty$ thanks to the presence of $e^{-\mu x}$, provided $\mu>0$).